# How to write a Web API route mapping so that it allows me make a parameter optional?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Web API service as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public UserProfile SearchByEmail(string siteName, string providerName, string email)
{}
```

I'd like to make the providerName optional and the below urls should work:

```
{0}: http://www.domain.com/sites/siteName1/providerName1/User/SearchByEmail?email=email1
{1}: http://www.domain.com/sites/siteName1/User/SearchByEmail?email=email1
```

I've written the below mapping:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "SearchUserByEmail",
               routeTemplate: "sites/{siteName}/{providerName}/User/SearchByEmail",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "User",
                    action = "SearchByEmail",
                    providerName = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
```

but it only supports the {0} url and doesn't work with the {1} url.

How to write the mapping so that it allows me make the providerName optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last token of an url fragment can be optional. You will have to change your route pattern to: `sites/{siteName}/User/SearchByEmail/{providerName}` if you want this to work. Or my recommendation if a parameter is optional is to pass it in the query string.